# How to relate an array of integers to an array of strings in the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymc

I'm a Python beginner who is starting to get familiar with the pymc library. In my program I'm generating random numbers between 1 and 100. When I'm generating random variables, it obviously returns an array with integers (in this case a 10 int array):

```
customer_names = customer_names.random(size=10)
```

The history of this post is that I want to relate each int variable to a specific name through a table, as if each name had an identifier, but I don't know how to implement it in the code.

What I want is that when I `print(customer_names)` instead of getting an array `[ 54 2 45 75 22 19 16 34 67 88]` I want to get `[ Jose Maria Carmen Alejandro Davinia Eduardo Carlos Fátima Marc Mireia]`.

I have tried the following:

```
def identificar_nombres(nc = customer_names):
    for i in range (0, 9): #in this case 9 because I'm generating 10 random numbers
        if nc[i] == '1':
            return 'ANTONIO' 
        elif nc[i] == '2':
            return 'MARIA CARMEN'
        else: return nc[i] # process repeatedly with all names in the name dataset

nombres = identificar_nombres(customer_names)
```

but without result.

Thanks!

Comment: What you can do create a dictionary of names like this dictionary = {"1": 'ANTONIO', "2": "MARIA CARMEN"} etc. and then access the names from the dictionary using dictionary[str(nc[i)]

Comment: @RishabhBatra Thankyou so much, another stupid thing, how can transform an array of random numbers, to an array transformed by the dictionary with the names ?

Comment: I found it, problem fixed ;) @RishabhBatra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary(key-value pair) to store the variables like this:

```
variables = {1: 'ANTONIO', 2: 'MARIA CARMEN'}
```

And access it like this:

```
customer_names = list(variables.values()))
print(customer_names)
```

Output:

```
['ANTONIO', 'MARIA CARMEN']
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Suman, only another stupid doubt, but if I have an array of integers with 10 random numbers, we can call it 'array_indicators'. How can I transform, using that dictionary, that array to another called 'names array' with the values of the dictionary (in this case, the 'values' are the names)

Comment: I found it, problem fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

By "without result", I am assuming you are getting the **else** statement.

This is because using `if nc[i] == '1'` you are comparing **class 'int'** to **class 'str'** which will never match. Try the following code:

```
if nc[i] == 1:
            return 'ANTONIO'
```

Alternatively, using dictionary(key-value) will be a better approach here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def identificar_nombres(customer_names):
  customerlist = []
  for i in customer_names:
      if customer_names[i] == 1:
          customerlist.append("ANTONIO") 
      elif customer_names[i] == 2:
          customerlist.append("MARIA")
  return customerlist

nombres = identificar_nombres(customer_names) 
print(nombres)
```